# ImportError: No module named rosserial_python

Tags: arduino, rosserial, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

While trying to run the [Hello World tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/rosserial_arduino/Tutorials/Hello%20World) in arduino using rosserial,i always get this error.

```
    File "/home/renjith/catkin_ws/src/rosserial/rosserial_python/nodes/serial_node.py", line 39, in <module>
    from rosserial_python import SerialClient, RosSerialServer
ImportError: No module named rosserial_python
```

I am running on ros kinetic and ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/237465/importerror:-no-module-named-rosserial_python/) by [renjith](https://answers.ros.org/users/27201/renjith/) on ROS Answers with karma: 28 on 2016-06-19

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Neur0n](https://answers.ros.org/users/27159/neur0n/) on 2016-06-22**:
Take a look at this asked [question](http://answers.ros.org/question/113671/catkin-package-cannot-find-own-message-type-python/) to see if your case is similar. Or did you correctly configure the CMakeLists.txt and package.xml to make the node track the rosserial package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am explaing what i did and this worked for me.

Follow the procedures given in the tutorial Arduino IDE setup http://wiki.ros.org/rosserial_arduino/Tutorials/Arduino%20IDE%20Setup upto the point where you gitclone it from gitclone repository.Then instead of `catkin_make` type in the following command `catkin_make -DCATKIN_WHITELIST_PACKAGES=rosserial` followed by `catkin_make install-DCATKIN_WHITELIST_PACKAGES=rosserial`.Now go to  your workspace/src/rosserial where you will find 11 packages including rosserial.Now repeat the last two commands that you typed in for all of these packages like `catkin_make -DCATKIN_WHITELIST_PACKAGES=rosserial_arduino` and `catkin_make install-DCATKIN_WHITELIST_PACKAGES=rosserial_arduino` so on till `catkin_make install-DCATKIN_WHITELIST_PACKAGES=rosserial_xbee`.Now follow the tutorial from the point where you go to arduino sketchbook `cd <sketchbook>/libraries`till the end.

---

Originally posted by [renjith](https://answers.ros.org/users/27201/renjith/) with karma: 28 on 2016-06-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0